# using ILogger with factory Class and dependency injection in C# using framework4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, factory, nlog

I want to build infrastructure that write to log using dependency injection and initialize the NLog.logger instance in factory class, not with unity 
like this:

_logger = LoggerFactory.Resolve();
someone as any idea how to do this?

thanks

Comment: The answers to this are too broad, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want an example how to do this correctly in  my code

Comment: You need to be more specific about which frameworks you are using - is it MVC 4, 5 or 6? Do you know which DI/IOC framework you're using, eg. [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx), [TinyIOC](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC), [MVVMLight/SimpleIOC](http://www.guruumeditation.net/ioc-and-di-with-mvvm-light/) or one of the many other flavours?  Or perhaps you're using [.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) with built-in DI?  Lots of scope for a range of different answers.